# Tailwind load different images on breakpoints

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to load different images on breakpoints, one for mobile view one for desktop or lg view. But the image is not loaded at all.

I can have just one i.e. for mobile like so:

```
<img src="./images/mobile/image-header.jpg" alt="" />
```

Now i did some research how to change a image on a break point and i found two solution but neither is working for me:

Solution 1:

```
    `<div class="bg-[url('./images/mobile/image-header.jpg')] lg:bg-[url('./images`/desktop/image-header.jpg')]"></div>
```

with this solution when i investigate the DOM i can actually see the that the correct image is getting loaded but it is nor rendered onto the page:

[image]

Solution 2:

I can make a use of `tailwind.config` like this:

```
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        backgroundImage: {
          "mobile-header": "url('./images/mobile/image-header.jpg')",
          "desktop-header": "url('./images/desktop/image-header.jpg')"
        }
      },
    },
  };
```

and in my html:

```
<div class="bg-mobile-header lg:bg-desktop-header"></div>
```

Using this approach i can also see that the correct image is rendered for the correct break point:

[image]

I am using tailwind CDN in on top of my header:

```
<header>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</header>
```

I am not using any framework just a `index.html` file at the root of the folder with the images directory also at the root

Comment: I would say don't do either and use a [<picture>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element instead.

Answer (score 0):

That should work normally. You probably missing the size in your container.
can't add a background to a size-less div

https://play.tailwindcss.com/jK7iIUvK1a